# MVC4 missing login popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i just downloaded mvc4 template into my VS2010 and i have regular view for login instead of jquery popup described by many blogers, like here for example [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic2.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those articles were written for the beta version of Visual Studio 11.  The final templates shipped with 2012 do not have this functionality.

Comment: Whaaat? read your self, i wrote i just download it from microsoft website and i am using VS2010, and it doesn't work, for VS2012 also doesn't work.

Comment: @kosnkov - Whether we're talking about 2010 or 2012 is irrelevant.  During the beta of MVC 4, the templates included an ajax popup.  These were removed for the final version, both in 2010 and 2012.  The article you reference refers specifically to Visual Studio 11, which was the beta version.  You can downvote all you like, but it doesn't change the fact this functionality is not there in the release version of MVC 4.

Comment: @MystereMan Yes exactly popups removed from final version of mvc4. I just wondering why? found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505251/what-happened-to-the-popup-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc4

Comment: @bigb - Yes, although I believe the new single page application site template available in VS2012.2 Update has the popup again (though I haven't checked, I would hope it does or it's not really single page)

Comment: VS2012.2 Update doesn't bring a new template

Comment: @bigb - Perhaps i'm just imagining this then http://www.asp.net/single-page-application - `The ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update ships a new template for building single page applications`

Comment: @MystereMan looks like it is relevant to ASP.NET but not to ASP.NET MVC4

Comment: @bigb - It's not.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx `A new Single Page Application template for ASP.NET MVC is also now included`

Comment: @MystereMan Ok i agree it has some new templates but they are not doing "login popups"